# How do you clean install a program?

Tags: installation, ardour

I fear I may have deleted all of the loops in Ardour and would like to do a clean install. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all configuration files and re-install, do the following..

```
sudo apt-get purge ardour
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ardour
```

There is a nice apt-get summary over [Here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/588)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to uninstall, clean and install it again:

To uninstall:

> ./waf uninstall

To clean up results of a build (objects, libraries, etc) use

> ./waf clean

Now, the build

> ./waf configure
>
> ./waf

To install again:

> ./waf install